# Control on non-client area incorrectly painted as transparent

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I customised the non-client area of window frame following  the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dwm/customframe?redirectedfrom=MSDN. On this non-client area, I want to add a container dialog and a few custom buttons. I cannot get the color I want to be painted on my container dialog. Instead, it is always painted transparent in that area. The issue is demonstrated in the 2 figures below (the background there is for demonstrating the transparency).

The effect I want is:
[image]

But what has been painted is:
[image]

As you can see, the container dialog is wanted to be painted as purple but is painted as transparent and so is the customer picture button (gray cross inside circle).

The code I used to handle the WM_PAINT for the container dialog is:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
Gdiplus::Graphics g(hDC);
Gdiplus::Color clr(255, 0, 0, 0);
clr.SetFromCOLORREF(RGB( 85, 107,  47));
Gdiplus::SolidBrush b(clr);
g.FillRectangle(&b, rc.left, rc.top, RECT_WIDTH(rc), RECT_HEIGHT(rc));
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

I googled but could not find topic of similar issue (may be I didn't use the right keywords). I am not familiar in using winapi to draw non-client area. Any help pointing out what I have missed or direction to solution is much appreciated.

A VS project that demonstrate the problem is linked below:
[CustomCaption.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui2gabja5nv1mzh/CustomCaption.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can [this custom-chrome project](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome) help you?

Comment: Can't see how it can help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the **alpha channel**. Try `Gdiplus::Color clr(255, 0, 0, 255);`. And could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: I have include a link to a minimal project that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you update Windows to the latest? I reproduce it in the 20H2 Version but there is no problem in the 21H1 Version. It seems the problem has been fixed by the later update.

Comment: I take your suggestion and updated to 21H1 version. The symptom is changed but not fixed. The WM_PAINT message is not received and therefore the container dialog is not painted. If you change the container dialog color to red `clr.SetFromCOLORREF(REG(255,0,0))` you will not see the red container dialog painted.

Comment: How is the `WM_PAINT` message not received? Can you reproduce it in 21H1 Version? I'm sorry I have no way to debug because of environment.

Comment: Go to "Project->Property->Manifest Tool->Input and Output->DPI Awareness" and change the value to "None". That will have the original symptom back. Or otherwise you will need to handle the DPI recalculation in the code.

Comment: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/dwm/customframe) shows how to add something to what DWM draws. The link does provide code needed to customize the title bar.
Removing the call to **DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea** should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Tom, That link is exactly where I read for doing the DWM draws. Yes, the issue resolved If the call to DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea is removed. But I don't understand why control is painted transparent in non-client area. Could you share more knowledge on that?